# Troubles running Mahout 0.9 text-processing examples

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

**TL/DR** : are `mahout 0.9` examples compatible with `hadoop 2.4` ?

### My problem:

I would like to classify a bunch of documents using Mahout 0.9. To do so, I'm following the example described [here](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html).

I'm on windows and trying to go full native (ie, no cygwin). I already dispose of a local hadoop 2.4.1 cluster.

I downloaded the mahout sources and compiled it according to the [wiki](https://mahout.apache.org/developers/buildingmahout.html) :

```
mvn "-Dhadoop2.version=2.4.1" -DskipTests clean install
```

I then tried to execute the example with the following example :

```
hadoop jar $Env:mahout_home/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver seqdirectory -i Decomposition -o output
```

It all seems to work : I'm getting logs showing the mapreduce job begins to run. However, I quickly get the following errors :

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.ja
va:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(CombineFileRecordReader.java:126)
        at org.apache.mahout.text.MultipleTextFileInputFormat.createRecordReader(MultipleTextFileInputFormat.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.ja
va:157)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but c
lass was expected
        at org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader.<init>(WholeFileRecordReader.java:59)
        ... 15 more
```

According to the various links I found, it seems to come from code intented for Hadoop 1.0.

Am I missing something, or are mahout provided examples not suited for a Hadoop 2.4 cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the object  *TaskAttemptContext*  is a Interface in the version 2.4 of Hadoop and the job was expecting a class (version 1.1.2 Hadoop).  *TaskAttemptContext*  has been changed in version 2.0.

Comment: Does it mean there is no way to execute mahout examples on a hadoop2 cluster ? What's strange here is the fact that this problem is supposed to be solved via `-Dhadoop2.version=2.4.1`.

Comment: The problem here is that the class `CombineFileRecordReader` create a instance in the method `initNextRecordReader` of the class `TaskAttemptContext` but in the version 2.4 it's a interface, so if you want use the version Hadoop 2.4, must rewrite mahout.